# how can we improve the PouchDB performance when we save a few attachments?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

Recently I am studying PouchDB as our project maybe use it, i did some investigation and found when saving many attachments, it will take a lot of time to do it.

Now I have a requirement: save **30M size** png file as attachments to a doc. I tried 2 ways to solve it,but all of them are not perfect, how can we improve my functions' performance?

1.save these files at the same time, it will take about 71237ms:

```
function saveImage(imgSource30M2) {
    var blob = base64toBlob(imgSource30M2, 'image/png', 1024);
    imgSoucrce30m = blob;
    var t1 = new Date();
    db.put({
        _id: 'my0112doc',
        _attachments: {
            'myattachment.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            },
            'myattachment2.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            },
            'myattachment4.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            },
            'myattachment5.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            },
            'myattachment3.png': {
                content_type: 'image/png',
                data: blob
            }
        }
    }, (err, doc) => {
        var t2 = new Date();
        console.log("save in pouchdb timeoff:", t2.getTime() - t1.getTime());
    });
}
```

2.save these files one by one , this way it will take more time , it will take about 226221ms.

```
const t11=new Date();

function addNewDoc(imgSoucrce30m) {
    var blob = imgSoucrce30m;
    addAttachment(5, blob, t11);
}

function addAttachment(counter, blob, t1) {
    var nameImg = counter + '.png';
    db.get('my0112doc', function(err, doc) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        db.putAttachment('my0112doc', nameImg,doc._rev ,blob, 'text/plain', function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            if (counter >= 0) {
                addAttachment(counter - 1, blob);
            }
            if(counter < 0 ){
                var t2=new Date();
                 console.log("for loop save in pouchdb timeoff:", t2.getTime() - t11.getTime());
            }
        });
    })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `base64ToBlob()` is likely to be a very expensive operation on such huge data. If you can directly work with Blobs (e.g. via the File object in an `<input type="file">` then you should
2. In Chrome 43+ PouchDB stores Blobs directly to IndexedDB as-is, so it's probably the best experience you're going to see performance-wise (Safari and old Chrome are slower)
3. You might want to break up your Blobs into many smaller Blobs. Another trick is to use multiple PouchDBs and then writes your Blobs to them in parallel - this way, IndexedDB can parallelize under the hood because they are separate IndexedDB databases.

Otherwise though, it's hard to say what you should do, because it may just be that writing 100s of MBs of Blobs to IndexedDB is going to be pretty slow, and you don't have a solution other than to show the user a loading spinner (be sure to use a Web Worker in that case so that it doesn't [block the DOM](http://nolanlawson.com/2015/09/29/indexeddb-websql-localstorage-what-blocks-the-dom/).)

Comment: here base64ToBlob() is just used to get some blob source, because i want to test the performance of saving large images, so i set my  var t1 = new Date() after it.  from your second answer,  it seems you still don't suggest to store large images in pouchdb, right? also i cannot give the user i loading spinner, because i want to save images automatically,  the user needn't to know this function.

Comment: in my real project, actually i can get Blob directly, but we cann't stand pouchdb takes so long time to save images, so i want to find if there is a way to improve the performance. :P